# How can I show the name of the link without http://, https://, and everything that goes after .com and other similar domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

In my view I'm displaying the link in a such way:

```
<a href="<%= @casino.play_now_link %>"><%= @casino.play_now_link %></a>
```

So, `@casino.play_now_link` can be like this: `https://www.spinstation.com/?page=blockedcountry&content=1` What I need, is to display only this part: `www.spinstation.com`. I tried `gsub('http://', '').gsub('https://', '')`, and it works, but how can I remove the part of url name after `.com`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regexes at all for this sort of thing, use [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) from the standard library:

```
URI.parse(@casino.play_now_link).hostname
```

or, for a more robust solution, use [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable):

```
Addressable::URI.parse(@casino.play_now_link).hostname
```

Of course, this assumes that you've properly validated that your `play_now_link`s are valid URIs. If you haven't then you can add validations that use `URI` or `Addressable` to do so and either clean up existing `play_now_link`s that aren't valid URIs or wrap the parsing and hostname extraction in a method (which is a good idea anyway) with some error handling.

Comment: yes correct. Thanks @mu is too short. URI is better for this.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple way one can use

```
.split('/')[2]
```

which is regex based and depends on the '/' in your url. 
But as @mu is too short mentioned: **URI is better** for this.